# linux console how to change the codepage to dos cp437

Tags: linux, terminal, debian, codepages, codepage-437

I want to view some ansi-art on the linux local-console. (my setup:raspberry pi3 / newest raspbian - no x11)

i've tried many different settings in raspi-config, dpkg-reconfigure console-setup, /etc files, environment vars but i had no luck yet. do i need a special pcf font to get it working?

a reliable way to enable it for remote terminals would also be great.

thanks in advance

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on the S.E. related sites http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ or http://superuser.com. Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what your data uses (see [chart](http://www.ascii-codes.com/)).  Codes `0..31` are a problem unless you have a program that can map those codes to a printable value (as noted in *[Why does showconsolefont have different output in tmux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321784/why-does-showconsolefont-have-different-output-in-tmux/321979#321979)*, the `showconsolefont` program *does* this mapping of `0..31`).

Most of the *usable* fonts for the Linux console are "psf" fonts: having a header which tells which Unicode values each glyph corresponds to.  Using that, along with a known character set (cp437), you could convert the data or "play" it using an application which knows how to do this:

- You could convert it using [`iconv`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/iconv.1.html) or [`recode`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/recode), or
- The line-drawing (`128..255`) could be done using `luit` in a UTF-8 console.

Comment: this actually lead me to a solution using setfont with some downloaded cp437.psf and executing unicode_stop. thanks